# Lebesgue Integral on measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Any help with this questions is appreciated.

$f$ - non negative and integrable. Given $\epsilon > 0$, Prove that $\exists$ a measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E) < \infty$ such that $\int_E f > \int f - \epsilon$.

Can I choose $E$ so that in $E$, $f$ is bounded from above?

Comment: What does P.T. mean?

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited

Comment: Consider the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ where $f_n=f\cdot\chi_{G_n}$ and  $G_n=\{\, -n\le x\le n \mid f(x)\le n\, \}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra - The sequence of functions that you mentioned is increasing and converge pointwise to $f$ and so I can apply MCT. I still don't get how this gives a measurable set.

Comment: Select a $G_N$ so that $\int f_n=\int_{G_N} f>\int f-\epsilon$. $G_N$ is measurable.

Comment: @DavidMitra Can I always do this. What is it that guarantees I can do this. And can I always choose this $G_N$ so that $f$ is bounded from above on $G_N$.

Comment: The MCT gives you the result: $\int f_n\rightarrow\int f$, so for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ so that $\int f-\int f_n<\epsilon$ for $n\ge N$.  Note that the $G_n$ were defined so that $f$ is bounded above on $G_n$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ where $f_n = f \chi_{G_n}$ and $G_n=\{\, -n\le x\le n \mid f(x)\le n\, \}$. $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise. MCT gives, $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$, so for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $N$ such that $\int f - \int f_n < \epsilon$ for every $n \geq N$. So, $\int f_N = \int_{G_N} f > \int f - \epsilon$.

The problem's solution is by DavidMitra. Just wanted to put it together.